# Unsupported format while using the correct format

Tags: c#, file, format

Im getting a "NotSupportedExeption was unhandled by user code - the specified path format is not supported" error, even thou I use a string as is requered.

```
string path = folder + "/" + filename;

fileByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path); // error here
```

any idea to what the problem is?

edited the code to this

```
string path = Path.Combine(folder, filename);

fileByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

the path is "F:\Web\Opgaver\Skirmer\Hjemmesiden\BETA\Skirmer 17-04-2012\Skirmer 17-04-2012\Billeder\Galleri\F:\Web\Opgaver\Skirmer\Hjemmesiden\BETA\Skirmer 17-04-2012\Skirmer 17-04-2012\Billeder\Galleri\2011\Vingsted\DSC_0001.JPG"

Error still happens. What I see is that ReadAllBytes requeres a string that shows the path, that I got, but it still shows error

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine` instead of the + operator to combine a path to a file

Comment: what file are you trying to read? can you add more details?

Comment: im trying to read the file DSC_0001.JPG. What other informations would you like to know?

Comment: I don't think File.ReadAllBytes throws `unsupported format exception`. Your bug should be somewhere else.

Comment: The erro sounds "NotSupportedExeption was unhandled by user code - the specified path format is not supported"

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `/` in the path, as the slash is an invalid character in Windows. Use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to create it instead:

```
string path = Path.Combine(folder, filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to use a backslash, or rather the property `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` that returns the correct separator regardless of the file system:

```
string path = folder + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + filename;
```

Or you can use the `Path.Combine` method:

```
string path = Path.Combine(folder, filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact value of `path` variable?
Additionally, you should use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to concatenate path parts into a full path.

As the documentation for `File.ReadAllBytes` states:

```
 NotSupportedException  - path is in an invalid format.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path is not in the correct format:

```
NotSupportedException  path is in an invalid format.
```

[MSDN: system.io.file.readallbytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the path you posted in your edited question really is the path you are trying read from then the reason you are getting the exception is because you have two colons in the path. The drive letter is repeated twice (`F:\...F:\...`).

The reason you end up with that path depends exactly on the contents of `folder` and `filename` in your call to `Path.Combine()`. It is unlikely that both `folder` and `filename` both start with the full path since `Path.Combine()` will return `filename` as the combined path in that case. It is most likely that your `folder` variable already contains two copies of the base path, with two drive letters and hence two colons and therefore causing the `NotSupportedExeption`, before you call `Path.Combine()`.